# Add line numbers to GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs

How can I add line numbers to Emacs?

Please explain, I'm an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're running it in default mode, it's in the menu:  Options > Show/Hide > Line Numbers.  Then Options > Save Options to save it for future sessions.

If you're running it in a terminal (`emacs -nw`), then it's `M-x line-number-mode`.  `M-` is usually the Windows key, but may be <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or you can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>x</kbd>.

(Edit:  The above only affects the mode line.  For line numbers in the margin, you want `M-x linum-mode`, or more likely `(setq global-linum-mode t)` in your `~/.emacs`.)

Comment: That only displays the current line number in the mode line

Comment: @Florian: Good catch. I added the instructions for `linum-mode` to the answer.

Comment: Ok, you've been faster - deleted my answer

Comment: `(setq global-linum-mode t)` is not working when I add this line to .emacs.d/init.el, I just change it to`(global-linum-mode t)` and it works. Any reasons why?

Answer (score 21):

Add `(global-linum-mode t)` to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

Comment: This worked for me.  Heads up for Windows users - this file is located in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming directory, and is called ".emacs".    Just add (global-linum-mode t) at the end of the file.

Comment: Could also be in the "C:\Users\username\" directory

Comment: how do you add a space between the line number and the text? because adding just (global-linum-mode t) shows the line numbers and the text without spaces.